# Hide copy source from VisualBasic CopyDirectory in C#

Tags: c#, .net, directory, copy

Using this namespace:

```
Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;
```

I am copying a source folder from on our network to the user's computer using this line of code:

```
FileSystem.CopyDirectory(networkDir.FullName, localDir.FullName, UIOption.AllDialogs, UICancelOption.DoNothing);
```

This opens up that nice copy window we are all familiar with, which shows:

1. that my application is not hung up and is thinking.
2. how long the transfer will take.

Problem is that this window also shows the source and destination locations of the copy. I don't really want the user to see the IP and exact file path where the files are coming from.

I would like to avoid creating a big recursive foreach loop to make a directory copier, on top of having to provide an active UI that shows that the program is thinking. Are there any good workarounds or other solutions to achieve a directory copy without the source location being made public?

Comment: Did you try the default behaviour `UIOption.OnlyErrorDialogs`?

Comment: Yeah. That hides where the source is coming from but also makes it look like the application is hung up. OnlyErrorDialogs hides the transfer window. The directory copy can sometimes take upwards of a minute.

Comment: Then you should take into consideration another approach like the use of robocopy as a background task and chekc the progress in another part of your UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
source location being made public
```

Do you control the source being downloaded from? If it's from a webserver you could make the whole thing ephemeral, and even use a hosts file entry to obfuscate the IP:

"Downloading from http://daves.server.honest/downloads/onetime/23i23i34248723084r/dir.zip"

Could be essentially useless to the 2nd person who tries to use the path.

Sadly if you're on a network drive rather than a webserver, your options are slightly more limited since it all has to be 'real' :/

Comment: Unfortunately, the source has to be a network drive, so I can't do that. Good thought though.